# generate page with jquery cannot read cookie with flex

Tags: jquery, apache-flex, cookies

When I generate a page with jquery (by including a startup.js in a html page), i cannot acces a cookie through flex.

startup.js

```
function init_element() {
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $("#accountBarDiv").css("position", "absolute");
    $("#accountBarDiv").css("left", "0px");
    $("#accountBarDiv").css("background-color", "transparent");     
    $("#accountBarDiv").append("<iframe id=\"ifrId\" style=\"width:10px;height:10px\"></iframe>");
    $("#accountBarDiv").append("<object classid=\"clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000\" codebase=\"http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0\" width=\"230px\" height=\"70px\" id=\"ogra2\">  <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://localhost/ogra/bin/ogra.swf\"/>        <param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"/>        <param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"/>               <embed src=\"http://localhost/ogra/bin/ogra.swf\" quality=high width=\"230px\" height=\"70px\"  name=\"ogra2\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\">  </embed></object>");

});}    init_element();
```

I have also included a script.js. It contains a function test() and this will return "hello".

I ogra.swf I call a return ExternalInterface.call to function test and my answer is unfortunatly null.

When I change my startup.js in a str with html and body and the object and embed (difficult to post it here because of all the quotes) And I just document.write the str. I can access my cookie perfectly.

Too bad they ordered me to write the startup.js in jquery.

Does anyone have any idea why i can't access my cookie in my flex application?

And of course, the jquery stuff works in FF not in IE.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Flash applications does not send cookies. This is a known limitation of Flash because the NPAPI binary makes the connection by itself directly, without going through the browser.

This is known as "Flash Cookie Bug", listed in, e.g. Known Issues of SWFUpload.
http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#knownissues

You might what to try some workaround, e.g. use Javascript to parse `document.cookie` and inject session cookie into Flash with `flashvars`, then send the session cookie via POST/GET.

A SWFUpload plug-in called "Cookies" does the same thing.
http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#plugins